# Identificar o que está na porta USB

Tags: delphi

Quando um dispositivo é conectado a uma porta USB, o sistema operacional identifica o aparelho. Por exemplo, no Windows, pode-se ver quais aparelhos estão ligados às portas USB no Gerenciador de Dispositivos.

Preciso verificar, programaticamente, se um dispositivo específico está conectado ao computador. Existe alguma forma de se obter essas informações em Delphi?

Comment: Olá, você poderia verificar se essa API do windows possui o que você precisa fazer? [WinUSB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540196(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Resolve, mas adiciona um nível de complexidade :\ Mas obrigado!

Comment: Talvez você poderia utilizar WMI, é uma API mais fácil. Mas depende do que você quer fazer

Comment: Precisa ser somente em Delphi? Pode ser outra linguagem como Python por exemplo?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Pode ser em Python, desde que utilize uma biblioteca que possa ser utilizada em Delphi (estou a realizar manutenção em um sistema já existente).

Comment: A biblioteca libusb funciona no Windows, mas como é uma biblioteca em C, teria de fazer a interface (declarar as funções com protótipo compatível com C)

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/pen-drive-usb-com-delphi é open source, acredito que pode ajudar

Comment: Qual a versão do teu delphi?

Comment: @Artur_Indio 2006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue esse exemplo, testei aqui no delphi xe6:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

{$MINENUMSIZE 4}

const
  IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY =  $002D1400;

type
  STORAGE_QUERY_TYPE = (PropertyStandardQuery = 0, PropertyExistsQuery, PropertyMaskQuery, PropertyQueryMaxDefined);
  TStorageQueryType = STORAGE_QUERY_TYPE;

  STORAGE_PROPERTY_ID = (StorageDeviceProperty = 0, StorageAdapterProperty);
  TStoragePropertyID = STORAGE_PROPERTY_ID;

  STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY = packed record
    PropertyId: STORAGE_PROPERTY_ID;
    QueryType: STORAGE_QUERY_TYPE;
    AdditionalParameters: array [0..9] of AnsiChar;
  end;

  TStoragePropertyQuery = STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY;
  STORAGE_BUS_TYPE = (BusTypeUnknown = 0, BusTypeScsi, BusTypeAtapi, BusTypeAta, BusType1394, BusTypeSsa, BusTypeFibre,
    BusTypeUsb, BusTypeRAID, BusTypeiScsi, BusTypeSas, BusTypeSata, BusTypeMaxReserved = $7F);
  TStorageBusType = STORAGE_BUS_TYPE;
  STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR = packed record
    Version: DWORD;
    Size: DWORD;
    DeviceType: Byte;
    DeviceTypeModifier: Byte;
    RemovableMedia: Boolean;
    CommandQueueing: Boolean;
    VendorIdOffset: DWORD;
    ProductIdOffset: DWORD;
    ProductRevisionOffset: DWORD;
    SerialNumberOffset: DWORD;
    BusType: STORAGE_BUS_TYPE;
    RawPropertiesLength: DWORD;
    RawDeviceProperties: array [0..0] of AnsiChar;

  end;

  TStorageDeviceDescriptor = STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    mmo1: TMemo;
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  function GetBusType(Drive: AnsiChar): TStorageBusType;
  procedure GetUsbDrives(memo: TMemo);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  GetUsbDrives(mmo1);

end;

function TForm1.GetBusType(Drive: AnsiChar): TStorageBusType;
var
  H: THandle;
  Query: TStoragePropertyQuery;
  dwBytesReturned: DWORD;
  Buffer: array [0..1023] of Byte;
  sdd: TStorageDeviceDescriptor absolute Buffer;
  OldMode: UINT;
begin
  Result := BusTypeUnknown;

  OldMode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
  try
    H := CreateFile(PChar(Format('\\.\%s:', [AnsiLowerCase(Drive)])), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil,
      OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    if H <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    begin
      try
        dwBytesReturned := 0;
        FillChar(Query, SizeOf(Query), 0);
        FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
        sdd.Size := SizeOf(Buffer);
        Query.PropertyId := StorageDeviceProperty;
        Query.QueryType := PropertyStandardQuery;
        if DeviceIoControl(H, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, @Query, SizeOf(Query), @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), dwBytesReturned, nil) then
          Result := sdd.BusType;
      finally
        CloseHandle(H);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    SetErrorMode(OldMode);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetUsbDrives(memo: TMemo);
var
  DriveBits: set of 0..25;
  I: Integer;
  Drive: AnsiChar;
begin
    Cardinal(DriveBits) := GetLogicalDrives;

    for I := 0 to 25 do
      if I in DriveBits then
      begin
        Drive := AnsiChar(Ord('a') + I);
        if GetBusType(Drive) = BusTypeUsb then
          memo.Lines.Add(Drive);
      end;
end;

end.
```